# Correct way of starting a foreground service in KMM from my shared multiplatform composables inside my shared/commonMain?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kmm project where I have all my multiplatform composables inside the shared/commonMain module. Now the question is, How do I start a foreground service from some user action from the ui shown from shared/commonMain?

My project structure looks like the following.

```
MyKMMProject/
|-- build.gradle.kts (root project build.gradle.kts)
|-- settings.gradle.kts
|-- shared/
|   |-- src/
|   |   |-- androidMain/
|   |   |   |-- kotlin/           <-- Kotlin code shared with Android
|   |   |-- iosMain/
|   |   |   |-- kotlin/           <-- Kotlin code shared with iOS
|   |   |-- commonMain/
|   |   |   |-- kotlin/           <-- Kotlin code shared across all platforms. This is where I have my composables defined and on click of a button here, a foreground service should start for android.
|   |-- build.gradle.kts (shared module build.gradle.kts)
|-- androidApp/
|   |-- src/
|   |   |-- main/
|   |   |   |-- java/
|   |   |   |   |-- com.example.mykmmproject/  <-- Android-specific code where I need to register my service in AndroidManifest.xml and also start it on some callback which would denote button was clicked
|   |   |   |-- kotlin/
|   |   |   |   |-- com.example.mykmmproject/  <-- Kotlin code specific to Android
|   |   |-- res/
|   |   |   |-- ...                            <-- Android resources (layout, drawable, etc.)
|   |-- build.gradle.kts (androidApp module build.gradle.kts)
|-- iosApp/
|   |-- src/
|   |   |-- main/
|   |   |   |-- kotlin/
|   |   |   |   |-- com.example.mykmmproject/  <-- Kotlin code specific to iOS
|   |-- build.gradle.kts (iosApp module build.gradle.kts)
```